# How to press/click a button in WebView using Espresso

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I have an android SDK and upon pressing a button opens a Webview where i can see a button whose html view is as below:

```
<button type="button" class="button js-analytics-submit" id="submit-try-sample" data-analytics-category="Sample" data-analytics-label="Intro">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="58" height="58" viewBox="0 0 58 58" id="button-logo
" class="button__logo">
  <path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M37.32 21.933l2.877-2.876-.626-.625c-5.04-5.043-13.247-5.043-18.29 0-4.832 4.833-5.03 12.568-.6 17.643l-2.876 2.875.625.625c5.042 5.043 13.247 5.043 18.29 0 4.832-4.832 5.03-12.567.6-17.642zm-14.79-2.25c4.144-4.144 10.76-4.344 15.142-.6l-1.64 1.64c-3.488-2.86-8.644-2.664-11.9.593-3.256 3.256-3.454 8.412-.594 11.9l-1.608 1.608c-3.743-4.382-3.542-11 .6-15.142zm12.94 18.642c-4.143 4.144-10.76 4.344-15.142.6l1.64-1.64c3.488 2.86 8.644 2.664 11.9-.593 3.256-3.256 3.454-8.412.594-11.9l1.608-1.608c3.743 4.382 3.543 10.998-.6 15.14z"></path>
</svg>
  <span class="button__wrapper" id="button-text">
    <span class="button__text">
      Let’s do this!
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Now i'm trying to press/click a button using the following but nothing works :(

```
onWebView().perform(script("return document.getElementById(\"submit-try-sample\").click()"));

onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID, "submit-try-sample")).perform(webClick());

onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//button//span[contains(text(),'do this')]")).perform(webClick());
```

The above code doesn't throw any error and executes successfully but it doesn't click the button.

Comment: Finally figured out the culprit. While debugging further i got to know 'touchstart' was the causing the issue. My submitEventType was set to 'touchstart' but when i set it to 'click', my statement started working. Took couple of days to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand what you mean in your answer, but here is simple way to click on Button when it have an ID (id="button-text").

You can simply write

```
onWebView().withElement(findElement(Locator.ID,"button-Text")).
perform(DriverAtoms.webClick());
```

Comment: Well in my application source code, the eventType for the button was set to 'touchStart' and hence my test was not able to click the button. When the eventType was changed from 'touchStart' to 'click', it worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

add the below line of code in your before test section -

```
onWebView().forceJavascriptEnabled();
```

Reade more about Espresso Webviews http://www.qaautomated.com/2016/02/testing-web-views-using-espresso-web.html

Comment: Thanks for the response Anuja! Yes, i did set it before performing the action. BTW this is an issue with the eventType binding as it doesn't recognise the 'touchStart'. It works well with 'click'

Comment: Could anyone please check the below question, I am getting NoMatchingViewException while I perform click action, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76472775/navigation-view-android-kotlin-with-espresso-androidx-test-espresso-nomatching