# Navigation View Android Kotlin with Espresso - androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException

Tags: kotlin, android-espresso, android-navigationview

I am new to Espresso trying to write testcase of NavigationView menu item click.

Below method in HomeActivityClass

```
accountMenu is the NavigationView predefined class, actionView is the View predefined class

private fun updateNavigationItems() {
        with(binding.accountMenu.menu) {
           
        findItem(R.id.nav_account_legal).actionView?.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.item_title)?.text =
                getString(R.string.legal)
         }
    }
```

Below is the test class which I have implemented

```
@ExperimentalTextApi
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class HomeActivityTest2 {

    @get : Rule
    var myActivtyRule = ActivityScenarioRule(HomeActivity::class.java)
    
    @Test
    fun legal(){
        onView(withText("Legal")).perform(click())
    }
}
```

when I try to run legal method I am getting below exception

```
androidx.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: an instance of android.widget.TextView and view.getText() with or without transformation to match: is "Legal"

View Hierarchy:
+>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=1440, height=3120, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params={(0,0)(fillxfill) ty=BASE_APPLICATION wanim=0x7f150155
fl=LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN FULLSCREEN LAYOUT_INSET_DECOR SPLIT_TOUCH HARDWARE_ACCELERATED DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS
pfl=NO_MOVE_ANIMATION FORCE_DRAW_STATUS_BAR_BACKGROUND FIT_INSETS_CONTROLLED
bhv=DEFAULT
fitSides=}, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
```

Could you please help me on this.
I am stuck at this.
Thanks in advance.